# TensorFlow random_shuffle_queue is closed and has insufficient elements

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm reading batch of images by getting idea [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py) from tfrecords(converted by [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py))

My images are cifar images, [32, 32, 3] and as you can see while reading and passing images the shapes are normal (`batch_size=100`)

the 2 most notable problems stated in the log, as far as I know is

1. Shape of 12228, which I don't know from where I get this. All my tensors are either in shape [32, 32, 3] or [None, 3072]
2. Running out of sample

`Compute status: Out of range: RandomSuffleQueue '_2_input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 0)`

How can I solve this?

Logs:

```
1- image shape is  TensorShape([Dimension(3072)])
1.1- images batch shape is  TensorShape([Dimension(100), Dimension(3072)])
2- images shape is  TensorShape([Dimension(100), Dimension(3072)])

W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_ops.cc:79] Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [3072], got [12288]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1027] 0x7fa72abc89a0 Compute status: Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [3072], got [12288]
     [[Node: input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueue[Tcomponents=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, input/sub, input/Cast_1)]]
W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_ops.cc:79] Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [3072], got [12288]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1027] 0x7fa72ab9d080 Compute status: Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [3072], got [12288]
     [[Node: input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueue[Tcomponents=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, input/sub, input/Cast_1)]]
W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_ops.cc:79] Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [3072], got [12288]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1027] 0x7fa7285e55a0 Compute status: Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [3072], got [12288]
     [[Node: input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueue[Tcomponents=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, input/sub, input/Cast_1)]]
W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_ops.cc:79] Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [3072], got [12288]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1027] 0x7fa72aadb080 Compute status: Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [3072], got [12288]
     [[Node: input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueue[Tcomponents=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, input/sub, input/Cast_1)]]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1027] 0x7fa72ad499a0 Compute status: Out of range: RandomSuffleQueue '_2_input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 0)
     [[Node: input/shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueMany[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, input/shuffle_batch/n)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/HANEL/Documents/my_cifar_train.py", line 110, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 11, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Users/HANEL/my_cifar_train.py", line 107, in main
    train()
  File "/Users/HANEL/my_cifar_train.py", line 76, in train
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
  File "/Users/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 345, in run
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/Users/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 419, in _do_run
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.OutOfRangeError: RandomSuffleQueue '_2_input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 0)
     [[Node: input/shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueMany[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, input/shuffle_batch/n)]]
Caused by op u'input/shuffle_batch', defined at:
  File "/Users/HANEL/my_cifar_train.py", line 110, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 11, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Users/HANEL/my_cifar_train.py", line 107, in main
    train()
  File "/Users/HANEL/my_cifar_train.py", line 39, in train
    images, labels = my_input.inputs()
  File "/Users/HANEL/my_input.py", line 157, in inputs
    min_after_dequeue=200)
  File "/Users/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 453, in shuffle_batch
    return queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "/Users/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 245, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n, self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/Users/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 319, in _queue_dequeue_many
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/Users/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 633, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users
/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1710, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/HANEL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 988, in __init__
    self._traceback =

_extract_stack()
```

Comment: Hi @mrry Yes, I will send it to you, but I figured out the 2nd problem, I used the training_iterations to 20 which is less than 100 (batch_size) caused the insufficient elements. The 1st problem I guess is the thread size of my machine, it's 4 thread and 12228 = 4 * 3072

Comment: Yes @mrry you are right, I added all of these for debugging, image.show / set_shape,... The running version is the same as you said

Comment: The most likely issue is that sizes passed to `set_shape()` don't match the true sizes of the tensors that are being produced by `decode_raw` - perhaps something has gone wrong earlier in the pipeline. To find out the true shapes, you can do something like: `image_shape = tf.shape(image); ...; sess.run(image_shape)` to get the true shape.

Comment: I don't think it's the shape of the decode_raw is the problem, If you see to the logs, I print the shape of the batches and image, it's all correct @mrry

Comment: These shapes are based on numbers that you typed in manually, though. TensorFlow can't infer a shape for the output of `decode_raw`, because it depends on the size of the input string, which can vary from step to step. Therefore, it might have a different true shape from what you are expecting, and it's plausible that it will have shape `[12228]` (for some reason).

Comment: Looking more at your input code, it looks like you convert the images to `np.int32` arrays before writing them to the TFRecord file: `images_only = [np.asarray(image[1], `**`np.int32`**`) for image in images]`. However, you read them in as `tf.uint8` values, which means you will have four times as many values, and `4 * 3072 = 12288`.

Comment: You found the extra 4 multiplier, thank you :) I will try now and let you know.

Comment: @mrry Thank you very much, it works.

Comment: @mrry Make your comment an answer for more points. You are addicted to points aren't you? Remember that there are StackOverflow users who don't read comments. Also I don't recall Google search returning results based on the comments only the answers.

Comment: Could you please paste some code? Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem. Digging around the web, it turned out that if you use some `num_epochs` argument, you have to initialize all the `local` variables, so your code should end up looking like:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    # do your stuff here

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

If you post some more code, maybe I could take a deeper look into it. In the meantime, HTH.

Comment: Thanks! `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())` was exactly it!

Comment: Glad it helped. Since it is a quite common issue, could the OP please mark the answer as correct for further readers? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You're likely processing the parsed TFRecord example wrong. E.g. trying to reshape a tensor to an incompatible size. You can debug using a tf_record_iterator to confirm the data you're reading is stored the way you think it is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tfrecords_filename = '/path/to/some.tfrecord'
record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=tfrecords_filename)

for string_record in record_iterator:
    # Parse the next example
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(string_record)

    # Get the features you stored (change to match your tfrecord writing code)
    height = int(example.features.feature['height']
                                 .int64_list
                                 .value[0])

    width = int(example.features.feature['width']
                                .int64_list
                                .value[0])

    img_string = (example.features.feature['image_raw']
                                  .bytes_list
                                  .value[0])
    # Convert to a numpy array (change dtype to the datatype you stored)
    img_1d = np.fromstring(img_string, dtype=np.float32)
    # Print the image shape; does it match your expectations?
    print(img_1d.shape)
```

Comment: Phew, that was a rough bug, but your answer solved it. I had a `tf.py_func` node that returned the wrong type, but TF only shows a misleading error message about insufficient elements.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exactly same issue today and later I found it was the input data file I downloaded from "famous data set" (such as https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data) that caused the error: It has some empty lines at the end of the file. Remove the empty lines, the error was gone!

Comment: Exactly! You save my day! Thanks! I delete the blank line in the end of the file, problem solved!

Answer (score 4):

This could also be caused by a wrong tf record file name that doesn't exist at all. Make sure you have correct file paths specified before you do other checks.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the comments, the

```
Compute status: Out of range: RandomSuffleQueue '_2_input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 0)
```

was caused by the queue running out of data. This is often caused by thinking you have enough data for N iterations when really you only have enough for M iterations where M < N.

One suggestion for figuring out how much data you actually have is to count how many times you can read data before an OutOfRangeError exception is thrown by the queue.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem. However, I don't think my data is not enough. I have a dataset of 8000 samples, and I set the num_epoches of filename_queue to 2, so it should be 16000 samples to enqueue. My batch_size is set to 100, so it should iterate 160 times. However, I still have such "out of range" warnings, even if I put the iteration code into a try ... exception block which can catch OutOfRange exception. So any possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and none of the previous answers seemed to solve it so I will also chime in.

For me the problem ended up being the features list I was passing to parse_single_example. For whatever reason (since I am using a float_list ?) in my tfrecords file I needed to specify the length of the array in my features list or use tf.VarLenFeature ie:

```
feature_structure = {'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([FEATURE_SIZE], tf.float32),
           'outputs': tf.FixedLenFeature([OUTPUT_SIZE], tf.float32)}
d_features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature_structure)
```

Without this I kept getting the "random_shuffle_queue is closed and has insufficient elements" error which I am guessing is because my parsed example had no data in it.

Comment: how did you fix it last