# Tensorflow: tensor reshape error together with RandomShuffleQueue out of range error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have 2 errors that came together when I tried to run my file:

> Out of range: RandomShuffleQueue
>   '_1_input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has
>   insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)

The 'requested 1' is actually my batch size. I have tried to reduce my batch_size to 1 to see if the error occurs again. However, I'm unsure why the current size is 0 at all.

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a
>   tensor with 357604 values, but the requested shape has 89401

I have referred to an older thread:
[TensorFlow random_shuffle_queue is closed and has insufficient elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050071/tensorflow-random-shuffle-queue-is-closed-and-has-insufficient-elements), 
and I've checked that I've a similar problem since `357604 = 89401 * 4`, so I'm wondering where the 4 comes from.

The thread does mention that if I converted my files to TFrecords in `int32` and then I read them with `uint8` format, then I'll have 4 times more data. However, I can't tell where in my tfrecord file creation did I use `int32`. I tried to fix the problem by converting my tfrecords file in `uint8` forcefully (using the DataSet class from the tensorflow mnist file, i.e. from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets import mnist, and setting the `dtype = tf.uint8` for my dataset), I got another new error I can't identify:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin[0] == 0 (got 0) and size[0] == 0 (got 1) when input.dim_size(0) == 0
     [[Node: softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Slice_3 = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Shape_3, softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Slice_3/begin, softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Slice_3/size)]]

Caused by op u'softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Slice_3', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 103, in <module>
    FLAGS.log_dir)
  File "train.py", line 88, in main
    slim.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(predictions, labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/losses/python/losses/loss_ops.py", line 385, in softmax_cross_entropy
    return compute_weighted_loss(losses, weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/losses/python/losses/loss_ops.py", line 144, in compute_weighted_loss
    num_present = _num_present(losses, weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/losses/python/losses/loss_ops.py", line 179, in _num_present
    [0], [1]), [])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 431, in slice
    return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2234, in _slice
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected begin[0] == 0 (got 0) and size[0] == 0 (got 1) when input.dim_size(0) == 0
     [[Node: softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Slice_3 = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Shape_3, softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Slice_3/begin, softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Slice_3/size)]]
```

I'm trying to create train a model using TF-slim eventually. As there are very little tutorials available on the TF-Slim library, I've used the codes from:
https://github.com/mnuke/tf-slim-mnist
as a reference. Most of my code examples are with reference to the code from this link.

Comment: Can you point to the exact code you're executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess for the first problem is that you need to do:

```
sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())
```

This problem happens when you don't initialize the number of epochs of a `Queue`.